# How to insert a table single column value into another table column in sql server 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have two columns 1. Orders and 2. Billing_address here is my tables structure

```
[OrderID]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CustomerName] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
[OrderDate]    DATETIME       CONSTRAINT [DF_Orders_OrderDate] DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
[ShipDate]     DATETIME       CONSTRAINT [DF_Orders_ShipDate] DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Orders] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([OrderID] ASC)
```

Here is my Billing_address table structure:

```
    [b_id]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [bname]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [baddress] TEXT          NOT NULL,
    [bcity]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [bzip]     NUMERIC (18)  NOT NULL,
    [bcountry] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [bphone]   NUMERIC (18)  NOT NULL,
    [bfax]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [OrderID]  INT           NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Billing_address] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([b_id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Billing_address_Orders] FOREIGN KEY ([OrderID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID])
```

I am inserting user provided form data into Billing_address table, Billing_address table have a column name OrderID I want to insert value into this column from the Orders table column OrderID value, here is my insert query code:

```
com.CommandText = "Insert Into Billing_address(bname,baddress,bcity,bzip,bcountry,bphone,bfax,OrderID) SELECT ('" + name.Text + "','" + address.Text + "','" + city.Text + "','" + zip.Text + "','" + country.SelectedValue + "','" + phone.Text + "','" + fax.Text + "', OrderID FROM Orders";
```

I got error after executing this query, I have explain above what I want and this query i think not fitted for my requirements, please help me to achieve my requirement, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to get the OrderID linked to the billing address from your asp pages. And before continuing read about Sql Injection

Comment: `I have two columns 1. Orders and 2. Billing_address`.  You mean two tables?  `I got error after executing this query`.  And that error is...?

Comment: don't know how i can do this :(

Comment: ohh Shitt Sorry LittleBobby ... Two tables :( .

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, you are not actually selecting an OrderID from the Orders table, you're getting all of them; for this to work, you need to add a WHERE to that SELECT. Anyway, since you're actually inserting a completely new data row and only the order ID needs to match, a subquery probably isn't the right thing for the job.

You should first get the order ID for the order you're processing (you probably already have it available in your application, but if not, then just look it up); then do a simple INSERT using the new values and the order ID you already have.

And please use a stored procedure for this, or at the very least be sure to sanitize your inputs.
***You should never directly send user input to a database.***